# R.Java from Facebook SDK collides with application R.java

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, r.java-file

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook SDK to an application finished and running.

The Facebook login activity is embedded in the Facebook SDK and requires the generated R.java provided in the examples.

The problem is that there's a collision between my app R.java and the Facebook R.java and an image from my app is appearing instead of the close button of the facebook window:

in com.facebook.android/R.java

```
    public static final int com_facebook_close = 0x7f02000a;
```

in my app/R.java

```
    public static final int hm2x=0x7f02000a;
```

as you can see, both files have the same id and the facebook login window id using the wrong one.

I've tried to import com.facebook.android.R in the login activity but it doesn't work as the facebook login window is on the facebook sdk.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I finally found it !!! It took me plenty of tests to realize.

In the project properties the SDK was referenced as

> android.library.reference.1=../../facebook

which is a project on eclipse workspace but not the real directory where the SDK is stored.

Indeed, the facebook developers guide says:

> You must unselect the 'Copy projects into workspace' option so that
>   each of the sample projects retains a correct reference to the
>   neighboring SDK. However, this means that Eclipse creates a link to
>   the project in the SDK installation, rather than making a copy of it.
>
> (This is useful if you expect to update the SDK in-place in the future
>   and have your workspace's library project update accordingly. However,
>   if you choose to edit the SDK samples in the future, you may wish to
>   subsequently re-import them with a copy so as not to affect the
>   original versions.)

Now, this doesn't work because it seems the redirection is generating some problems and the app doesn't find all the sdk components it should.

Everything started to work when I manually hardcoded the link to the real SKD in the project.properties:

> android.library.reference.1=../../facebook-android-sdk-3.5.2/facebook

Comment: did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: @MrSuS Yes, I've completely cleaned the project. Then I've copied the R.java from the Facebook Example, finally I rebuilt the app regenerating the R.java. It still generates the same Ids and collides.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean and rebuild your project. That way new R.java will be created without conflicting ID numbers.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've completely cleaned the project. Then I've copied the R.java from the Facebook Example, finally I rebuilt the app regenerating the R.java. It still generates the same Ids and collides.

Comment: @user1778857 you shouldn't copy the R.java at all. R.java is being created by the compiler when you build your app. Delete the build/, gen/ and bin/ folders if you have them and then rebuild your project without copying the R.java file.

Comment: Hi Valerio, the facebook R.java has to be copied (that's the way as it works on the facebook example). If I don't copy it I've got a runtime exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$Layout at com.facebook.LoginActivity.OnCreate

Comment: If you're using the official Facebook SDK (right now I'm looking at 3.5.0 on an app of mine), you have to include the Facebook SDK as a library in your project. That way you don't have to copy files around. Take any of the examples shipped with the SDK, open it and you will see that the SDK is referred as a library (in project.properties you'll find a line like this: android.library.reference.1=../../facebook)

Comment: Hi Valerio, Yes I'm using the official Facebook SDK 3.5.2. I have included the library as a project and reproduced mostly everything as in the Facebook Login Example. In that example, the  com.facebook.android.R.java is included "as is" without sources in addition to the standard Facebook_SessionLoginSample.R.java (that has no images) automatically generated from the example sources. I've reproduced all project properties from the sample. The only difference I found is that in the sample the facebookSDK.jar is on the Android Dependencies and when I added it it appears in Referenced Libraries

Comment: @user1778857 I suppose you mean the SessionLoginSample. But that sample doesn't include any of the R files coming from the Facebook SDK. Anyway I see you managed to find where the error was. Regards :)